# How to design a custom Tabs while using ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I've been trying to style ActionBarSherlock so as to give my app the look I desire, but while I've succeeded with most, I've struggled with Tabs (which can be swiped with Fragments). I've so far failed to give it a custom background and text color, while also removing the border in between tabs.

What I currently have is

[image]

Whereas what I desire to make it look like is
[image]

Here's the code I'm using in the activity, the majority of which I've borrowed from another question on SO (I'll link it as soon as I find it again):

```
public class HomeActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
ViewPager mViewPager;
TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;
TextView tabCenter;
TextView tabText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);

    setContentView(mViewPager);
    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);


    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab 1"),
            MyFragment.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab 2"),
            MyFragment.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab 3"),
            MyFragment.class, null);
}

public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(),
                info.args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the ViewPagerIndicator library?

Comment: I haven't used any library other than ActionBarSherlock

Comment: Did you eventually figured out how to solve this?

Comment: Sorry for the late response Karey, I used the ViewPagerIndicator library that makes it possible.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the inheritence of FragmentPagerAdapter to do what you want. You should use the viewPager with the viewPagerIndicator library: [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)
Have a look, it's very easy to use and develop by SJ (Super Jake)